# Display division of UISlider Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

The goal of mine is to create a dynamic division of a UISlider, which outputs the interval values.

It should be created out of an array of values for example:

```
numbers = @[@7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16];
```

So far I've managed to get the UISlider working and dividing itself in equal intervals based on the elements of that array.

```
NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)(slider.value + 0.5);
[slider setValue:index animated:NO];
```

I just want to create as generalised as possible method for division, which actually displays values with equal interval gaps.

Any help with the displaying of those values will be highly appreciated.

Comment: FYI - you don't need the parentheses for your numbers in your array. Just do `@7` instead of `@(7)`. You only need the parentheses when wrapping a variable or a non-numeric literal expression.

Comment: okay, did that. But it doesn't answer my question. Do you have a suggestion of how can I solve this problem?